# JNA: Storing a copy of Java String after freeing native memory

Tags: java, jna

I have a native C structure holding a pointer to a string:

```
struct mystruct {
  char *name;
}
```

and a native function that allocates memory for the name:

```
void fill(struct mystruct *s, int count) {
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    s[i].name = strdup("something");
}
```

The corresponding Java structure and native method are

```
class MyStruct extends Structure {
  String name;
}
```

and `void fill(MyStruct[] structs, int count)` used to fill up some instances. I would then use this like so:

```
MyStruct[] structs = new MyStruct[10];
fill(structs, structs.length);
```

After I'm done, there is a clean-up routine that must be called `void free(MyStruct[] structs)`, which cleans up an entire array (all the memory allocated by strdup). There isn't a way to do clean-up on a struct instance-by-instance method.

The problem I am facing is that after freeing the array, the Java strings are corrupt. How can I create a copy each MyStruct instance so that I can free the native memory, and just deal with MyStruct instance that use pure Java strings?

Comment: Set the struct `name` fields to `NULL` after freeing them.  Otherwise JNA is going to assume it's a valid pointer and try to read from it.

Comment: I'd also recommend making the `name` field a fixed-width array, then you avoid the issue of allocating and deallocating extra memory.  YMMV.

Comment: I need to free the native memory, but then have a copy of the struct to pass around (with the actual string value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you free the native memory backing the `struct`, you should no longer reference the Java object, or you should create a new one with its own memory backing.

If you need to manage the memory manually, don't map the field to a `String` but use `Pointer` instead, e.g.

```
class MyStruct extends Structure {
    public Pointer name;
    public String getName() { return name == null ? null : name.getString(0); }
}
```

In general it won't directly *hurt* to use a JNA `Structure` after its native memory backing has been freed, as long as you don't call `Structure.read()` or `Structure.write()` (note that JNA calls those methods automatically before and after native function calls).  However, make sure you know what you're doing if you choose to do so; there are safer ways to develop your code.

Comment: Yes, the read/write synchronization is what I used to fix the problem. It is only a stop-gap for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Although MyStruct does not implement the `Cloneable` interface, it has a `clone()` method inherited from `java.lang.Object`. Thus I believe, you can overwrite `clone()` without interfering with JNA.

```
class MyStruct {
    String name;

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        MyStruct myStruct = new MyStruct();
        myStruct.name = new String(this.name);
        return myStruct;
    }
}
```

You could now iterate `structs` and clone each element.
In case this doesn't work because of extending `Structure`, you could change the above method, so a different (non-native) class is instantiated.

```
class MyStruct {
    String name;

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return new NonNativeStruct(new String(name));
    }
}

class NonNativeStruct {
    private String name;
    public NonNativeStruct(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Note that you disobey the contract `x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass()` doing this.

Comment: I haven't tired this exactly, although I did try to create a cpy of the string like you did `new String(old_struct.name)` and still saw the corrupt. Maybe my test was bad..

Comment: Did you copy before you used `free`?